# MediaElement play only portion of a video

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, kinect

I'm working on a kinect app that needs a video that respond to user gestures. So each gesture recognized I have to launch a video. No problem if I change the source of my MediaElemnt every time I need a new video, only performance are very poor (I don't wanna see loading lag between one video and other). So I'm trying a different video management, now I have only one long video composed by all the videos. What i have to do now is playing only one time and only a portion of the video. Using time Span I can navigate through the video timeline.

```
TimeSpan portionstart= new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5);
MainPlayer.Position = portionstart;
```

But in this way the only thing I'm doing is to move the MainPlyer to a specific point. In this way the player will play the movie until the end. There's a way to create a "portion" of the video by TimeSpan?